# .NET 5 not showing up in the Registry

Tags: .net, .net-5

I have .NET Framework 4.8 installed and it shows up in my registry when I want to check the version. Like in below image:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWfH6.jpg]

Now after I install .NET 5.0 and I try to check my registry, it doesn't mention v5 at all. Then how will I know that I have .NET 5.0 installed? Also why doesn't it show up in the Registry? Could anyone please help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: .NET 5.0 is not the next version of the .NET Framework 4.8, it's the next version of .NET Core 3.X, it doesn't shows there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the .NET Framework Registry keys. .NET Framework's last version is 4.8 and that is the last version you will see under those Registry keys. .NET 5 (otherwise known as .NET Core) is a cross-platform framework that does not get installed in the same way as .NET Framework.