# What is the difference between .NET5 and .NET standard?

Tags: .net

It has been said that .Net5 is unified version of all .Net versions, that is, .Net Framework,.Net core, and mono.But what is the difference between .Net5 and .Net Standard???

Comment: .NET 5 is actually .NET Core 5, not the `unified version` MS Marketing talked about. It *replaces* .NET Framework. Compared to .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 and 6 contain all the .NET Framework APIs that were chosed for migration. Some, like ASP.NET WebForms, weren't migrated and can't run on .NET. .NET 5 is a runtime, .NET Standard isn't. You can't create standalone .NET Standard applications, only libraries

Comment: "It has been said that .Net5 is unified version of all .Net versions, that is, .Net Framework,.Net core, and mono" -> *who* said that? That's completely incorrect.

Comment: Another change is that there's no .NET Standard in the .NET 5+ wave. .NET 5 is now the cross-platform basic runtime. Platform-specific applications target use different targets, allowing them to use target-specific APIs,  like `net5.0-windows` for desktop applications.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  MS people *did* say that, multiple times, creating quite a bit of confusion. People that used .NET Core at the time took this for what it was - marketing. People that didn't know the difference ... Oops. A SQL Server MVP told me 3 years ago how ".NET is going to be unified, forget about Core" - yeah, right.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto from a marketing perspective it worked. People that would never migrate to .NET Core 5 in less than 10 years, actually started migrating from .NET 4.8 to .NET 5.0 because it was just a small change, right? That was the point of the whole exercise

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A very small change, I imagine... It's all still the same, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017402/net-5-not-showing-up-in-the-registry/66017463#66017463 :)

Comment: @AlexKameron you can read about .NET 5 and .NET Standard in [The future of .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/). Immo Landwerth is a nice guy. He writes code, not articles talking about [.NET Unification](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/). That was his manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 5 removes the need for .NET Standard. Actually, you may think of .NET 5 as the evolution of .NET Standard. However, .NET 5 is not a formal specification but an actual implementation. Also, the release of .NET 5 marks the end of .NET Framework.
Read more in this post:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/